# YAJULEE (Yet Another Java UnsatisfiedLinkError Exception), even though the library exists and is in all paths

Tags: unsatisfiedlinkerror

As the title says, I'm having a problem with a very simple (or so I thought) exercise in using JNI.  I've gone through as many UnsatisfiedLinkError questions as I can stand here, but have found nothing that addresses this particular simple version of it.  On Ubuntu 18.04.01 I've written a small, simple bit of JNI in C++, the important part of which is:

```
public class AJniClass {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary( "MyNativeLib" );
    }

}
```

This is compiled and linked into `/usr/local/src/MyProject/lib/libMyNativeLib.so`.  The file is definitely present there.  Then I have a Java program `MyTest.java` that instantiates `AJniClass`, which causes (or should cause) `libMyNativeLib.so` to be loaded when `JAniClass` is loaded.  I have `/usr/local/src/MyProject/lib` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  `MyTest.java` is successfully compiled and an executable `MyTest.jar` is created.  When I attempt to run the jar a la...

> java -jar MyTest.jar

...it fails with the following exception stack:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libMyNativeLib.so in java.library.path: /usr/local/src/MyProject/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2429)
> at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
> at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
> at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:37)

As you can see from the value of `java.library.path` the path to the library is known to the loader.  And as I said, the .so file in question is most definitely present and accessible.  I've been battling this for the better part of a day now, with my blood pressure reaching levels I've not seen for some time.  Would anyone care to save me from an impending stroke and give me a clue as to what's going on here?